# how to append unlimited number of html elements through ajax success function?

Tags: java, ajax, playframework

i want to append unlimited number of HTML elements with data given as comment. This is my ajax:

```
function ajaxsubmit(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"
    }).success(function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
      });
    }
```

and my HTML part:

```
<div class="post" id="result"></div>
```

this is my serverside function:

```
public static Result ajaxupdate(){
    String done = "test";
    return ok(done).as("text/html");
}
```

This function is appending only once, and if I click for the 2nd time, it is not appending. Is it because I should have different ID's each time? How is that possible (like in stackoverflow how several comments work!)

Thanks, in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$('#result').html(data);` the content of `#result` is replaced with the new data.
To append the new data to `result`, use

```
$('#result').append(data);
```

Comment: oh yeah, this is what i want. simple but i was just lost in flooding thoughts.. :D. great man, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Each comment on stack overflow would have some sort of ID associated (probably from the database storing all the stack overflow data, which would be unique, and I'm guessing that would be used in some way as the element id.

Eventually, if you had a full commenting system, you'd probably want to return JSON from your ajax call. This JSON could maybe look like this:

> {"id":"12345","text":"Text for the comment","user":"Andy"}

And then you might parse this and add it to your page with '12345' as the containing elements ID, or something!

Failing that, for the time being you could always save the ID using jQuerys [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/%20data%28%29) function. This will store the ID against the element in jQuerys own cache. This way it wouldn't need to be unique.

<del>Either way, I'm sure the non-unique element ID will be why it's not showing.</del>

**Update**

Duh, course, Carsten is absolutely right, but hopefully there might be some good information in this post for you still! :)

Comment: oh okay, i see. thats cool what you mean, i will give a shot now

Comment: I was wrong about the element ID being why it's not showing by the way (see my update), Carsten was right when they said it's because of the Load function overwriting the content with the new ajax result!

Comment: yeah, sure. that information about rendering json and doing the job is also great, because that would solve other issues regarding getting more information thru callback.. anyway, thanks thanks! :)